# Binding fails without error

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a CustomListView that has controls like `TextBoxes`, `HyperLinks` and `Buttons`.
I can't share the exact Code, but please bear with me.

I have a list, say of type person with attributes like `personHeight`, `personWidth`, etc.
The binding to the list is done at the list level.

The issue is, that all values are fetched from the database, but only one is populated, the remaining are blank.
Also I didn't get any binding error in the Output Window. **What could be the issue?**

The general syntax of the XAML (where `personHeight` is one of the properties of the list object):

```
<CustomGridViewColumn SortOnProperty="personHeight">
    <CustomGridViewColumn.SortableHeader>
        <TextBlock Text="Person Height" />
    </CustomGridViewColumn.SortableHeader>
    <CustomGridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox x:Name="personHeightText" Text="{Binding personHeight}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CustomGridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
<CustomGridViewColumn>
```

The binding is done as follows:

```
<CustomListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyExpandableListViewItemStyle}"
                ExpandedDataTemplate="{StaticResource ExpandedDataTemplate}"
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                x:Name="GridList">
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'but only 1 is populated, the remaining are blank'? Does it mean that the Grid has rows with blank cells?
Also, Can you please show the code where you are binding the DataSource to the Grid?

Comment: I've added that code to the question

Comment: @AnishaJain : What about the query? will it gives the expected result?

Comment: I had put a breakpoint at the load and checked the values... everything was aavailable

Comment: Make sure that the "attributes like personHeight, personWidth, etc" are actually public properties, not fields, e.g. `public string personHeight { get; set; }`. WPF data binding only works with public properties.

Comment: what is the meaning of `but only 1 is populated, the remaining are blank` ?

Comment: I don't see any issue in XAML, maybe your Styles aren't working as intended, but I think there's something wrong with your bound properties etc. With this small information we can only barely suggest.

Comment: If you can post the properties from your viewmodel as well that would be great, but in the meantime try running up Snoop and checking the bound properties for the control.  It will show you if the binding failed at least, rather than just not getting the updates, which potentially splits your investigation in half.